# Can I restore folder in root directory? soft bricked phone

Tags: restore

the quick back story is that I deleted a folder called custpack in root directory of my phone.
Now the phone will not boot. I can only access android stock recovery (android system recovery 3e)

I can detect the phone when I type the command adb devices.
command like adb usb, adb pull or adb push keeps giving me a message  "error:closed".

the only command that seems to work is adb sideload

is there a way I can tinker with the file system of the internal phone memory? what are my options? the phone does have an sd card slot. so is it possible to flash a zip file that somehow restore the folder back? if so how do I create the zip file?

I do have a backup of the deleted folder in my PC

Comment: You need fastboot around now. Find out what key combo gets you the bootloader.

Comment: Flash a custom recovery with a file manager if your stock one doesn't have one already. Put the folder on your SD card using a PC, then insert your SD card into your phone and mount. This should allow you to restore the folder since you already have root.

Comment: unfortunately there is no custom recovery available. I'll try to get to fasboot. But my gut feeling , I will only get error:closed message. I think My only hope is some tools like SP flash tools that is made for mediatek SOC  phone ..

Comment: no luck using aroma file explorer , neon and non neon version.. it just says installation aborted.